# screen not update(setState), until window resize

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have no experience with keys and starting just now,
Below code is perfectly reproducible code, and works on [dartpad](http://dartpad.dev),

Code is of a basic list app, but the `floatingActionButton` to add item(s) to the list, is broken,
the `onPressed` function has a `print(ctr)` statement, which works correctly, but the app screen does NOT update(or change), unless the window of the browser is resized, please have a look,

Please note, that rarely it works correct, but once in many attempts,

```dart
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: SimpleListPage()));
}

class SimpleListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SimpleListPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SimpleListPage> createState() {
    return _SimpleListPageState();
  }
}

class _SimpleListPageState extends State<SimpleListPage> {
  int counter = 0;

  List<Widget> items = <Widget>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    items.add(Text("Simple list"));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: items,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          int ctr = counter++;
          print(ctr);

          setState(() {
            items.add(SimpleListItem(
              key: ValueKey<int>(ctr), // even `UniqueKey()` NOT work
              data: Data(null),
            ));
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Data {
  Data(this.text);
  String? text;
}

class SimpleListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const SimpleListItem({
    super.key,
    required this.data,
  });

  final Data data;

  @override
  State<SimpleListItem> createState() {
    return _SimpleListItemState();
  }
}

class _SimpleListItemState extends State<SimpleListItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String? text = widget.data.text;

    if (text != null) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(text),
      );
    } else {
      return TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        ),
        autofocus: true,
        onSubmitted: (String input) {
          setState(() {
            widget.data.text = input;
          });
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Also, please suggest, is using `ValueKey<int>(counter++)`, good approach, or some other, also is `ValueKey` good for this purpose,

thanking you

I tried using `UniqueKey`, in place of `ValueKey`, but no progress,

I read a few Medium posts, Youtube videos, especially the official keys video, but no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change usage of your `ListView`

```
body: ListView(
  children: items,
),
```

with `ListView.builder`

```
body: ListView.builder( 
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (_, i) => items[i],
),
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but may i also ask the reason, if you know, that why it not work without builder

Comment: Because the ListView compares old **items** with updated items by **reference**. If references are the same then it will update nothing